# Is there an algorithm or API for determining word type from context?

Tags: algorithm, api, parsing

I have input sentences such as "I went to cup the ball." (cup is a verb) and "I drank milk from cup." (cup is a noun) and I need to figure out whether each word is a noun, adjective, verb, etc for my application. I am no linguist and I would rather not spend days/weeks writing some effective sentence parser. Does there exist a free script or API that can accomplish this task? The faster the algorithm the better because I plan to parse entire essays at a time.

I am writing this application in **C#**, so if possible that language is prefered.

Comment: You are looking for a natural language parser. It should not be difficult to find a service, library oder executable implementation. I remember using one in JAVA, it was pretty simple, although I don't recall the name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Stanford CoreNLP for .NET](http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html) or [SharpNLP](https://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/). I've never actually used these, so I can't comment further. I've played with [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) in Python before.

Comment: It took forever to get the Stanford CodeNLP to work correctly but it fills my need. Thank you!